# Is $f$ continuous or not continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Given a  function  $f\colon [0,1] \cup (2, 3] \to [0, 2]$ defined by

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} x & 0 \le x \le 1 \\ x-1 & 2 < x \le 3 \end{cases}$$

My  question is that is  $f$ is  continuous  or not  continuous ?

My attempt  :  Suppose  if i take  $c=0$ , then  for  every $\epsilon >0$ , there  is exist $\delta$  such that  $|x-c| < \delta$  such that  $|f(x)-f(c)| <\epsilon$

But  here  $\lim_{ x\rightarrow 0^+}f(x)= -1$ and  $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{-}} = 0$

So  $f$  is  not continuous

Comment: Break it into cases and see what happens at each of the given intervals.

Comment: $f$ is continuous.  $f$ is clearly continuous on $ 0 < x < 1$ and $2 < x < 3$. Now,  since $f$ is not defined on the left of $0,$ you just take the limit from the right. The same thing for the point $x = 1$ and $x = 3$. You can further formalize this using the definition

Comment: @Azlif  But  domain say that $ x= 1,3$  so  we  can  not exclude them

Comment: How do you conclude that $\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x)=-1$ when $f$ is positive on a small enough neighborhood to the right of zero? Moreover, how do you even define $\lim_{x\to0^-}f(x)$ when $f$ is not defined on a neighborhood to the left of zero?

Comment: @jasmine I didn't exclude them.  Like I said, $f$ is continuous on $0 < x < 1$ and $2 < x < 3$. Now,  it is letf us to show that $f$ is also continuous at $x = 0,1,3$ by taking only one side limit. (Why this can be done  is clear from the defintion of limit)

Comment: thanks u@Math1000  sorry that  was  my false logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start with $\epsilon - \delta$ and then move to $\lim_{x \to 0 ^-}$ etc. : I don't get your approach because you either use limits or $\epsilon - \delta$ as methods, but you seem to use some convoluted combination of them and then get confused.

So you stick with one method.

For example, sticking with $\epsilon - \delta$ : Given $\epsilon > 0$, we note that for any $x \in [0,1] \cup (2,3) = S$, we have $S \cap B(x , \frac 12) \subset [0,1]$ or $S \cap B(x,\frac 12) \subset (2,3]$ , for example ($\frac 12$ is not special, anything less than one works). So, we can work with just these sets.

Now, for any $x$ and $y \in S \cap B(x , \frac 12)$, observe that $|f(y) - f(x)| = |y-x|$ (from  definition of $f$ on both the pieces). Thus, we may take $\delta  = \min\{\frac 12 , \epsilon\}$, because $\delta < \frac 12$ will bring any $y$ into the same piece as $x$, then $\delta < \epsilon$ will ensure $|f(y) - f(x)| = |y-x|  < \delta = \epsilon$ in this piece. Thus, we are done by $\epsilon - \delta$.

---

If you wanted to argue via limits, then only one - sided limits can be spoken of at $0,1$ and $3$. For example, it is obvious that $\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0^+} x = 0 = f(0)$ and similarly for $1$ and $3$. For the other points, the double sided limit can be argued similarly, depending on which the piece the point you take is in.

Answer (score 1):

When trying to determine if a function is continuous you don't have to jump right into the formal definitions. Start off by graphing the function:

[image]

You now review the graphs of both continuous functions and ones with discontinuities in their domain. If this picture fits a known pattern in your collection, then you can hazard a guess before working out a more technical explanation.

If this is a new pattern, then ask if the output value $y$ in $y = f(x)$, as it 'lives' over $x$ in the domain, 'behaves'.

Here the domain consists of two disjoint intervals with 'space' between them. So the output values 'live' over one or the other 'separated' interval pieces.